# SWIG with function that takes a numpy array as argument and return type

Tags: python, numpy, swig

I want to access C functions from Python. Is there a canonical way of writing a SWIG interface for a function with a signature in Python: np.array -> np.array and an equivalent signature in C of e.g. (float*, int) -> (float *, int)?

The [cookbook](http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/SWIG_NumPy_examples.html) mention int -> list and inplace modifications of np.array.

Comment: Are you trying to access a Python function from another language, or another language's function from Python? If the function is written in another language, what does the function take and return, in that language's terms?

Comment: I've tried to clarify. Let me know if it's still not clear

Comment: I believe the [official docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/swig.interface-file.html) may be more useful to you, particularly the parts about input arrays and argout arrays.

Comment: There is a collection of typemaps for exactly this. See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/swig.interface-file.html